# Doctrine2 many-to-one association with nonexistent entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have wiki-like articles in my database. They have given id (and NO generated). Article can have links to another articles. There can be links to (yet) nonexistent articles.

I didn't used any orm in this project. (It's from time when I learn how to code...) There was no problem. I just executed select with join, and when there was no target article, this behave like if there is null instead.

Then I move to Doctrine2 (and Symfony2). How can I do it?

As far I don't use doctrine many-to-one and I do it manually.

Article:

```
class Article
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Link", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $links;
}
```

Link:

```
class Link
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="links")
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $targetArticleId;
}
```

getting target article is something like:

```
//...
$link; //some Link object
$targetArticle = $em->getRepository('Article')->find($link->getTargetArticleId());
if ($targetArticle) {
    //target article exists
} else {
    //target article don't exist
}
//...
```

**QUESTION:** Can I do same thing with Doctrine2 association? Maybe I need change something in databese?

Comment: Didn't you tried? That should work. Also you can self-reference your article entity as links doesn't seem to have any other fields.

Comment: @DonCallisto I tried using ManyToOne with nullable. Command `doctrine:schema:update` give me sql with foreign key constraint, so I remove this one. Then I caught `Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException`.

But it gave me many other exceptions when used with DQL JOIN statement.

Comment: So you're telling me that you don't want the constraint beetween article and link?

Comment: @DonCallisto Something like that. I want keep orphan for future and manage it.

Comment: You can have a foreign key and have a null field, do you know?

Comment: @DonCallisto I know. But I do NOT want null, I want id of Article which NOT YET exists (but may exists in future, when someone add it). Like red links in wikipedia.

Comment: So the only possibility for you is to manage your field "by hand" and write a custom method into a repository for fetch eventually associated links.